# How to create weekly calendar which show week dates

Tags: android

How can I create a weekly calendar which displays only the current week date, with two buttons *Next week* and *Previous week* like this:

[image]

I just want 5 or 7 text views which display dates from sunday to saturday (or monday to friday), with 2 buttons which show next week or previous week dates.

Like this screen:

[image]

Comment: hii did you fix it.if yes can you please help me..

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View) project has exactly the same features you are asking for.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can start from here: [**android-times-square**](https://github.com/square/android-times-square), an open source project you can download the source code to study. **[Month Calendar Widget](https://github.com/JoseGD/MonthCalendarWidget)** is another open source project that it could be helpful for you.

Comment: is show in gridview all month i just want single week at a time